# Making a wireless lavalier microphone with ESP8266-07

Tags: audio, wireless, esp8266

I'd like to make a lavailer microphone and receiver using two ESP8266-07 Wifi modules.

I'm using a condenser microphone with it's own preamlifier using 5V.

I want to compare my signal with 300kHz triangle wave (class D amp like) to get 300kHz pulses.

Can I feed this signal to the ESP and transmit it, receive it, and decode it through an LC filter and feed to camera (after some regulation?)

Comment: THis will not work well at all with a very inefficient use of spectrum  with no CNR to SNR improvement factor that wideband FM offers

Answer (score 1):

WiFi is not something you can use to transmit just any modulated signal you like.

Your only access to it is as a network connection.

You will have to collect your data and put it in packages to be transmitted.  You submit those to the network stack to be sent to the receiver.  The receiver snags the data from the radio waves and passes that to your program.

It doesn't work the way you seem to think is does, but you should be able to make something work.

I doubt you will be happy with it.

The time delay for packets over wifi is generally higher than you want for live audio.  Tens of milliseconds are noticeable when you have voice and video.

Class D amplifiers are difficult to build - I suspect it will be much more difficult for what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not so that you only connect a signal to one module and you get it out from another. These modules either work as communication peripherals for computers or their internal processor is programmed to perform the needed data communication, interfacing and actual data processing functions.

The module has for example inputs and outputs for common digital audio, common instrumentation bus, analog input+ADC and also PWM outputs. But these do nothing without a program. As well no wireless data communication happens until there's a properly configured network + an application program which transfers its data via that network.

The manufacturer surely sells a developer's kit for this module. That kit surely contains hundreds urgently needed software modules. Using them is possible only for experienced programmers. But they contain probably stuff worth tens work years. Without developer's kit it's practically impossible to create anything useful which uses parts this complex.